# Can't get get object method to call other object method

Tags: ruby

I have built a program to practice object class and method creation.  I'm a noob.  Here's my code:

```
    class Orange_Tree

    def initialize 
        @age = 0 
        @height = 0.3 
        @yield = 0 

        puts "The orange seed you planted has grown into a sapling, what will you call it?"
        @name = gets.chomp
        puts @name + "?!?  What a glorious name!  I see great things in this sprout's future."
        puts @height
    end

        # Creates instance variables of this object upon creation.
        # Prompts user for input and assigns answer to @name.

    def talk
        puts "You spend a little time each day talking to " + @name +".     "
        @height += @height * 1.5
        if @yield == 0
            if ((@height >= 1) and (@height < 3))
                @yield +=  2
            elsif ((@height >= 3) and (@height < 7))
                @yield +=  5
            elsif @height >= 7 
                @yield += 10
            else 
            end

            puts "Well that certainly helped!  Even if your neighbours did think you were crazy.  Here we are 1 year later and " + @name.to_s + " is now " + @height.to_s + " metres tall and now has " + @yield.to_s + " oranges."
        else
            puts @name + "'s produced all their fruit for this year."
        end
    end

        #Method for helping the tree grow.
        # Multiplies height by a factor of 1.5.
        # Increases yield by continually greater number relative to the @height instance variable.
        #Updates user with a string including new values of instance variables.

    def sing 
        puts "You serenade " + @name + " once a day."
        @height += @height * 2
        if @yield == 0
            if ((@height >= 1) and (@height < 3))
                @yield +=  4
            elsif ((@height >= 3) and (@height < 7))
                @yield += 10
            elsif @height >= 7
                @yield += 20
            else
            end

            puts "That's the trick.  I've never seen such growth!  Here we are 1 year later and " + @name.to_s + " is now " + @height.to_s + " metres tall and now has " + @yield.to_s + " oranges." 
        else
            puts @name + "'s produced all their fruit for this year."
        end
    end

        # Similar to talk method above.

    def eat oranges
        if @yield >= oranges.to_i
            puts "You can't take it any longer.  Those oranges look too delicious"
            @yield -= oranges
            puts "Mmmm....tasty."
        else 
            puts "There aren't enough oranges."
        end
    end

        # Method which allows user to eat their chosen number of oranges, if there are enough.

    def count
        puts "There are " + @yield.to_s + " oranges."
    end

        # Allows user to check the number of oranges.

    def too_old

        if @height > 150
                puts "There comes a time in person's life when you have to let go of childish fancies such as orange trees.  That time has sadly come.  Many good times were had and oranges ate.  Fairwell dear " + @name + ".  We'll never forget you."

                exit
        else
        end
    end

    # This method is called by the pass_time method.
    # If the if statement evaluates to true the user is shown message and the program ends.


    def pass_time
        @age += 1
        @yield = 0
        Orange_Tree.too_old
    end

        # Method which increases @age 1 year per call and ends the program when @age increases past 10.
        # Each year that passes resets @yield to 0.

end

tree = Orange_Tree.new
tree.talk
tree.count
tree.eat 1
tree.pass_time
tree.sing 
tree.eat 1
tree.count
tree.pass_time
tree.talk
tree.count
tree.eat 1
tree.pass_time
tree.sing 
tree.eat 1
tree.count
tree.pass_time
tree.talk
tree.count
tree.eat 1
tree.pass_time
tree.sing 
tree.eat 1
tree.count
tree.pass_time
tree.sing
```

Which when ran gives:

```
orange_tree.rb:97:in `pass_time': undefined method `too_old' for Orange_Tree:Class (NoMethodError)
    from orange_tree.rb:109:in `<main>'
```

After doing some searching on here, I think I know what the problem is.  That I have defined the "too_old" method as an instance method, which needs to be a class method for my program to work as desired (whenever the "pass_time" method is called, it calls the "too old" method.).

So I have changed the "too_old" method to:

```
def self.too_old

    if @height > 150
            puts "There comes a time in person's life when you have to let go of childish fancies such as orange trees.  That time has sadly come.  Many good times were had and oranges ate.  Fairwell dear " + @name + ".  We'll never forget you."

            exit
    else
    end
end
```

Which is giving me:

```
orange_tree.rb:82:in `too_old': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from orange_tree.rb:97:in `pass_time'
from orange_tree.rb:109:in `<main>'
```

So now I am stuck.  I'd appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

too_old is an instance method on the class Orange_tree. This means you have to call it on an instance of Orange_tree. In the original code, you were calling it on the entire class Orange_tree

Try this:

```
def pass_time
    @age += 1
    @yield = 0
    self.too_old
end
```

That one modification to your pass_time method allowed your program to run without error for me.

Comment: Thanks.  Runs without error for me also, but the program isn't running as it should.  The "too_old" method should be killing the program, so it seems it is not being called at all.

Comment: Alex, not home anymore so can't run it again, but just eye balling it, maybe there are not enough growths to reach the height > 150 before the program ends? Try setting original height as 120 or something similarly high and see if too_old kills it then. Or make a controller to let the user select actions and just keep selecting actions (this would seem to be a logical next step if you wanted to continue development)

Comment: Hey Lost, thanks for your reply.  Based off the the information I've ran the program with the @height instance variable is at ~380, when anything greater than 150 should exit the program.  I'll have another crack at it tonight or tomorrow and will update then.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Alex, sorry for the problem. I had approved another users edits to my answer since I thought it was mostly in my description of the answer and was more complete. Unfortunately, I didn't notice on my phone that they also edited part of the code which broke the solution. The self.too_old that I had originally included and have put back in seems to work fine. I tested it with an initial height set to 100 and the program ended with the first pass_time. To adjust the number of turns required to end the game, just set your starting height appropriately. Again, sorry for confusion caused by the edit.

Comment: That's weird.....if I run the program with the exact code in my original post (with your amendment) it fails to end.  However by changing the initialize method variable @height to start at 151 and calling exclusively "pass_time" once, the program ends as expected.  Doesn't make any sense so far.  Interesting stuff though.  Thanks so much for all your help.  Now I know how to call a method on an instance and not the class.  Appreciated.

Comment: Haha noob error, can't believe I missed it.  The last method I called in the original post brought the @height over the 150 but needed to call the "pass_time" method one more time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you call Orange_Tree.too_old method, you never creates a true instance of Orange_Tree class. When you do not create instance you never invoke class initialize method (initialize will be invoked when you call `Orange_Tree.new`). In your case initialize method would initialize @height variable to 0.3, but as it never happens, @height is nil, and that is why you get `undefined method`>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

my suggestion is to replace `def self.too_old` method with normal `def too_old` method and in your `pass_time` method create new instance of `Orange_Tree`

to sum up:

```
def pass_time
  @age += 1
  @yield = 0
  Orange_Tree.new.too_old
end
```

P.S.
In ruby we name classes OrangeTree not Orange_Tree (convention)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.  The error relates to the "pass time" method I believe.  If you look at the bottom of the first code block I did create an instance of Orange_Class with : tree = Orange_Tree.new.  The rest of the program works fine.  Its just that the "pass_time" is supposed to end the program once @age reaches a certain point.  This is the only thing that doesn't happen.

Comment: I meant to say the "too_old" method is supposed to end the program.